# Выпадающее меню само закрывается или глюк JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

Доброй ночи, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему.
Есть у меня две jsp страницы, одна это боковая панель и хедер с поиском, вторая это список компаний. Вторая страница подтягивает первую.

При нажатии на выпадающее меню оно сразу закрывается. Как это устранить?

Хочу добавить, если с первой страницы (по тексту ниже) убрать

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

и в конец страницы добавить

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

то выпадающее меню работает нормально, но автозаполнение в поиске перестает работать

код страниц:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Company</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/style.less"/>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.0/less.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<jsp:include page="../menuPices/navbarLeft.jsp"/>

        <div class="main-content">
            <h1>Companies</h1>
             <a href="<c:url value='/company/add/' />" class="btn btn-lg"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                Create company</a>

            </br>
            </br>
            <c:if test="${!empty listCompanies}">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-center" width="23">ID</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="120">Name</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="80">Email</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="80">Web site</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="60">Address</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="40">Created</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="40">Updated</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="50">Details</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="50">Edit</th>
                        <th class="text-center" width="50">Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${listCompanies}" var="company">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${company.id}</td>
                            <td>${company.name}</td>
                            <td>${company.email}</td>
                            <td>${company.website}</td>
                            <td>${company.address}</td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${company.created}" pattern="d-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss"/></td>
                            <td><fmt:formatDate value="${company.updated}" pattern="d-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a href="<c:url value='/companydata/${company.id}/' />"
                                                       span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file "
                                                       style="color: darkblue"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a href="<c:url value='/editcompany/${company.id}/' />"
                                                       span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-edit"
                                                       style="color: orange"/></td>
                            <td class="text-center"><a href="<c:url value='/removecompany/${company.id}/' />"
                                                       span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color: red"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </c:if>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#acInput').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON("/companySearch/", {
                    term: request.term
                }, response);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вторая:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/main.js"></script>
<div id="main-wrapper"/>
    <div class="left-sidebar">
        <div class="navbar-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
        <div class="nav-block">
            <div class="menu-content">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="sidebar-logo">
                        <a href="#"></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="left-navigation">
                        <li class="active" >
                            <a href="index.html"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>Main Page</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="<c:url value='/home/' />"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>My account</span></a></li>
                        <li class="parent"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i><span>Company</span></a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu"><li><a href="<c:url value='/company/' />"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i> All Company</a></li></ul>
                            <ul class="sub-menu"><li><a href="<c:url value='/company/add/' />"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Create</a></li></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/main.js"></script>
    </div>

<nav class="nav" style="background-color: #203745">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
            <form:form method="GET" action="/company/">
                <input name="name" id="acInput" class="form-control" placeholder="search..." size="60" maxlength="90" style="width: 400px; height: 30px;">
                <button type="submit">
                    <spring:message text="Add"/>
                </button>
            </form:form>
            </div>
        </form>

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
            <div class style="color: #66afe9">
            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>?languageVar=en"><spring:message code="general.EN"/></a>
            <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>?languageVar=ru"><spring:message code="general.RU"/></a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: От того что ты скинул код, так просто тебе вряд ли помогут, покажи живой пример если есть

Comment: Подскажите, как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в версиях

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```